# Can I use conditional operator in if condition from remote database or JSON in Java

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I want to show data from remote in Java, but I want to use the conditional operator in PHP end database with JSON output e.g

I want to write

```
if(position % 2 == 0){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

into this format or any simple way

```
if(position $2 phpapi.getOperator() 0)
```

can I use/get the conditional operator " == " from remote end API and use it in the "if condition". I just want to add a conditional operator in the PHP end database. or tell me any best way to get a conditional operator from the backend php panel.

Comment: No.  You can't just convert a string you get from another API to the `==` operator in Java.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this directly.

But you can get to the desired output with a little bit of explicit coding.

```
String operator = someBackendApi.getOperator();
Integer operand = someBackendApi.getOperand();

boolean result;
switch (operator) {
  case "==":
    result = (position == operand);
    break;
  case ">":
    result = (position > operand);
    break;
  // .. further cases ...
  default:
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported operator: " + operator);
}

if (result) {
  // do stuff
}
```

If your using Java 12 or newer, you can simplify the switch, by using a [switch-expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html);

```
boolean result = switch (operator) {
  case "==" -> position == operand;
  case ">" -> position > operand;
  // .. further cases ..
  default -> throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unsupported operator: " + operator);
};
```